# MySQL #1054 unknown column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1054

When running the query below, I end up with a MYSQL error in PHPMyAdmin:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'wd.Datum' in 'having clause'
```

This query belongs in a time reporting application, where users report time worked on projects on a daily basis. There's a table for days that are expected working days, a table of all employees and a table with information about the current work rate. The last table is also used to determine when a user was employed.
The idea is to get all working days and all users in order to (in a later query) select days that a user has forgotten to report times for. I want to limit the result set to days that users has been employed.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT emp.ID AS user
FROM (workdays wd, employees emp)
     INNER JOIN workrates wr ON (emp.ID=wr.UserId)
WHERE (wd.Datum<'2012-11-15')
GROUP BY WEEK(wd.Datum, 3), user
HAVING wd.Datum>=MIN(wr.FromDate)
```

(May be related to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13551 which is about a syntax change introduced in MySQL version 5, that causes this message if you forget certain parenthesis)

The MySQL server is running version "5.1.63-0+squeeze1" on Debian.

**EDIT**: I changed the first query row to

```
SELECT emp.ID AS user, wd.Datum
```

as suggested by Vijay, and the query works! Though I don't understand why.

Comment: what are your columns in table?

Comment: Try to use wd.Datum in your select.

Comment: Post SHOW CREATE TABLE employees; SHOW CREATE TABLE workdays;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every column you use in the `HAVING` clause of your query must be present in the selected columns. `HAVING` works on the calculated values (for instance if you use the `SUM()` function you can use the calculated sum in the `HAVING` clause.)

Also note that if you give a column an alias you have to use the alias in the `HAVING` clause.

For more information on hidden columns and `HAVING`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wd.Datum in your select.

Its common in sql, if you are using a column in having clause, you have to add that column in select. What happens is like it will create a virtual table with the columns you have selected and filter with the condition in having clause.

--- Make it as answered if it really answered your question.

Comment: Sorry, Lex gave a more detailed explanation and I can't select two answers :(